# Why npm tries to find package.json in the wrong directory?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, npm, package-managers

I'm having a web app with TypeScript, Angular and several dependencies.

npm of course is here also.
`package.json` was introduced to the project from the begging by `npm init` and right now it looks like that:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.8-d",
  "description": "Web App",
  "author": "Author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "MYURL"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "MYURL"
  },
  "homepage": "MYURL",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "debowerify"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "~13.0.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.2.0",
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.8.2",
    "debowerify": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^3.2.2",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
}
```

Also my file structure is like this:

```
Root
|-- tscode
|-- compiled
|-- html_files
|-- node_modules
|-- libs
| package.json
```

This think is that npm seems to work fine, everything is installed correctly I can add/remove dependencies BUT always I'm getting this working:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Projects/MyApp/tscode/package.json'
```

package.json is on the root folder as it should but still I'm getting this warning which is very annoying. As you can see npm searching for the json file in a folder one level inside instead on the root.

Also if I do:
`npm list --depth=0`

Then I'm getting a correct list of my dependencies BUT also: -> `/Projects/MyApp/innerfolder extraneous error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Projects/MyApp/tscode/package.json`

Any ideas?

Node version: v5.10.1 
npm version: 3.8.5

Note: This is happening to everyone in my team regardless OS.

**UPDATE:** It seems that there is a bug with npm. There are some open issues at npm repository such as:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9633
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10004

If something change I'll update the question with an answer (if provided)

Comment: when running the npm command, is your working directory the root directory of your project?

Comment: Yes I'm on the root folder.

Comment: what happens if you run `npm list --depth=0`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Delete node_modules folder
```

Then run :

```
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install
```